# Como faz para enviar 3 requisições do Curl de uma vez?

Tags: php, libcurl

Bom galera estou criando um sistema, mas estou com uma duvida queria que enviasse a requisição todas de uma vez pelo curl_init, tipo quero enviar para buscar em 3 servidores de uma vez

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se tem de ir buscar a 3 servidores então vão ter de ser 3 requisições, mas uma maneira de fazer é criar uma função que se responsabilize por todas elas:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $return;
}

$urls = array('url1', 'url2', 'url3'); // só tem de adicionar/retirar os serviços daqui
$datas = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($urls); $i++) {
   $datas['url_' .$i] = get_data($urls[$i]);
}

// ex: $datas['url_0'] = conteudos do primeiro serviço a que acedeu ('url1')
```

Comment: Obrigado Miguel pela sua resposta não deu certo no meu código mas me deu uma luz para eu ver como se faz obrigado mesmo :)

Answer (score 0):

**Bom esse era meu código, sou novo em PHP**

```
$ch = curl_init('http://meusite.com.br/servidor1.php'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=$id");
$teste = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```